# How to override or remove a control in Google Map API

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I was playing with Google maps for last two days and started understanding little bit about its functionality.

I was using Large Map i.e. `700 X 300` resolution map size and i was trying to implement controls used in small maps.

eg.

```
var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
 map.setCenter(new GLatLng(37.4419, -122.1419), 18);
 map.setMapType(G_HYBRID_MAP);
 **map.setUIToDefault();**
 map.enableContinuousZoom();

 var customUI = map.getDefaultUI();     
 customUI.controls.smallzoomcontrol3d=true;   //1. trying to override largezoomcontrol3d 
 customUI.controls.menumaptypecontrol=true;   //2. trying to override largezoomcontrol3d 
 map.setUI(customUI);

 map.enableRotation(); //3. Enabling rotation
```

Here in 1(a). Small zoom control is not getting visible until i remove the line `map.setUIToDefault()` and add one more line `customUI.controls.largezoomcontrol3d=false`. Although I was expecting that by writing above code those control will get overridden.

1(b). I tried to use `map.removeControl(Control:GControl)` where i was not able to pass the correct parameter. I wanted to remove `largezoomcontrol3d` from map but i was not able to make out how to refer to this control in the current map.

2. Same overriding problem is occuring here also. The only difference here is that both the controls are visible here `menumaptypecontrol` and `maptypecontrol`, here `menumaptypecontrol` is overlapping on `maptypecontrol`
3. I am trying to enable rotation on map but it is not working for me.

Comment: To remove a control in Google Maps 3, see this answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/8414938/132374

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thinking about map.removeControl you were quite closely to solution (if I got what you need). take a look here:

[Controls](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/controls.html)

so, you need just use [map.addControl](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html#GMap2.addControl) function to add exactly what you need instead of what you did.

sorry, forgot about map rotation. I think the following simple example of Google Map can help you (I just never played with rotation, but example looks very simple to learnt from it):
[Google Map rotation example](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/examples/aerial-rotation.html)

Comment: FYI, Google maps is now at version 3.  This solution is for Google maps 2.