# Google Maps Javascript API V3 - How to remove Custom Control?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have created custom controller by following http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/controls.html Is there any way to remove custom controller? is it possible to use setOptions() for this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

you can remove using this two function using removeAt() or clear() should accomplish the task.

or by it's position in MVCArray `map.controls[position] is an MVCArray`.

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#MVCArray

Comment: @Pratik- Can you explain with an example

Comment: I got it. map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT].clear(); Thank you

Comment: It's not working for me.I set disableDefaultUI: true too.but no change.is there any other change want to work this?

Comment: in my case works `map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT].pop()` cause I want to move my custom control back, to the form when map is hidden by user